# Auto-launch block _toHtml()

Tags: template, blocks

I need to include a block in another block and launch it directly.
What I do now is this code in the first block

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/block');
```

then on that newly created block I have this

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setTemplate('module/block.phtml');
    echo $this->_toHtml();
}
```

This works fine, but having a echo in a the block model I don't really feel comfortable.

Is there any proper way to auto-launch this template at call of this block?

== EDIT ==
After trying the solution of @Keyul Shah it doesn't display anything.
So here is a more precise code of what I did.

I'm trying to call the block from a Admin Widget Form, so I put this in my XML:

```
<reference name="widget_instance_edit">
    <block type="myModule/adminhtml_my_block" name="block_name" output="toHtml" template="myModule/toShow.phtml" />
</reference>
```

The module is called as everything in `_prepareForm()` displays, but the phtml is not displayed.
If I try to do `echo $this->_toHtml();` this time it has an error because it launches it before the parent.

=== FULL CODE ===
**app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Images/Edit.php**

```
class NameSpace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Images_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        // I want to call a specific block on top of the Edit Form
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_images_tagger');

        // addFields stuff
        ...
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Images/Tagger.php**

```
class NameSpace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Images_Tagger extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // This works but is ugly and want to change it in a correct thing
        $this->setTemplate('module/tagger.phtml');
        echo $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

The **tagger.phtml** doesn't matter.

[image: How it looks like]

=== Revision ===

After much more experience in Magento, I come back to this question and I realize that I was just on the wrong path.
The best way to do it is to create a block extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`, then simply call `$this->setTemplate('path/to/your.phtml');` and then get inspired by the phtml `report/grid/container.phtml`

Comment: What do you mean by "launch it directly"? What in the world are you trying to accomplish that native rendering does not handle?? Perhaps adding your template contents would help.

Comment: Thanks @benmarks I just put the important part of the code so you understand a bit more what I'm doing. It's on a Admin Widget Form.

Comment: From your question a $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/block')->toHtml(); should work, why is this no proper solution?

Comment: Not really because I will have to do `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/block')->toHtml();` so it will just put the same problem to the other block...

Comment: But all this is just to have a clean code, I can leave it like it is it works, but I hate leaving messy code like this I feel bad...

Comment: Don't give up on me now. Where *exactly* would you like to place your block, relative to the form buttons, header, etc.?

Comment: I just added a screenshot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. What i have done till now is....i called a block inside _prepareLayout()  like this   $this->setChild('alias',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('rewardpoints/adminhtml_customerstats1','useralias')
        );  after that created that block and tried to setTemplate inside it. Code execution is going inside it but its not setting the template file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better way is you can use via XML code.

In your `Layout.xml` file you can defile `output` attribute. So do not do manually via code.

**The below example will show you how to write in xml.**

```
<reference name="header">
       <block type="hssocialmedia/index" name="hssocialmedia_index" output="toHtml"
              template="hssocialmedia/hsmedia.phtml"
              as="mediashare"/>
</reference>
```

When your Block called It will automatically return the html format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I still have a few errors, I edited the original question so you may have a look.

Comment: have you create the myModule/adminhtml_my_block
NameSpace_myModule_Block_Adminhtml_my_Block File  is created or not?

Comment: Yes of course otherwise it wouldn't be working on the old version (with the dirty echo).

Comment: This will not work. If you make this instance an output block then it will echo twice.

Comment: @benmarks If you know answer then please let me know so I can also know new things

Comment: Will do Keyul - waiting on OP to explain his needs for doing this.

Comment: @KeyulShah do you have any idea on this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117369/need-to-add-custom-template-file-inside-form-container-magento-admin